# Using Same URL Format In Two Different Files With htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I have two files named article and category. I generated a URL format using the SEO URL structure. Sample:

example.com/article-title

example.com/category-title

Code:

```
RewriteEngine ON

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ category.php?category_url=$1 [NC,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ single.php?article_seo_url=$1 [NC,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

But there is a problem. I cannot use two url formats together in the .htaccess file. He sees the first line but ignores the other. But I want to use the same format for these two files. Can you help?

Comment: Okay, so let's take `example.com/foo-bar` - can _you_ tell me, whether that is supposed to be an article or category - without looking into your database? No? Then what made you think the server could make this distinction, at this point?

Comment: you need to include the **pre identifier**  like example.com/category/abcd... for category and for article example.com/article/xyz...

Comment: The only thing you can do, is use _one_ rule to rewrite this to _one_ single script - and then have that script go look the passed value up in the database, to determine whether it belongs to an article, or a category, and then branch into further processing logic accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Let's step back and think about this for a second:

I used to live at 1234 Stack Street. For reasons only known to the housing developer, they made the next street over Stack Court, complete with the same numbers. So... my mail would sometimes go to 1234 Stack Court if the postal service didn't pay attention. That was confusing enough. What you want is even more confusing: two houses at 1234 Stack Street, and somehow Apache just picks the right one. The problem there is fairly apparent: addresses need some unique portion to them.

Your options here are

1. Add something to tell Apache how to route it. So `example.com/article/some-article-here` would tell Apache that's an article and send it to `single.php?article_seo_url=$1`.
2. Point everything to one PHP script. So you would only have

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ router.php?page=$1 [NC,NE,L]
   ```

   router.php would then figure out if it was an article or category and call the proper PHP script. The catch here is that you have to make sure your categories and articles are unique in their URL, or we're back to the same problem you had originally.

Comment: This second method may work. I'll report back after I try it. Thank you so much :)